# List all the Dependent picklist and controlling picklist using lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to displaying controlling picklist values and dependent picklist values using lwc.

Fruit - Apple ,Orange, Grapes

Vegetables - Potato,onion,tomato

grains - rice,wheat, maize

Using the below code, it is getting displayed as

Fruit - Apple ,Orange, Grapes

Vegetables - Apple ,Orange, Grapes

grains - Apple ,Orange, Grapes

That is because of this line in JS code

this.TypeItemsFieldInfoOptions = this.TypeItemsFieldData.values.filter(opt => opt.validFor.includes(0));

It is getting only the values in array 0 and displaying in the picklist. How to resolve this issue?

JS code

```
export default class PicklistValuesLoadSheet extends LightningElement {
    @track value;
    @track TypeItemsFieldInfoOptions;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: TYPEITEMS_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', 
        fieldApiName: TYPEITEMS_FIELD})
    TypeItemsFieldInfo({ data, error }) {
        
            if (data) {
                this.TypeItemsFieldData = data;
                this.TypeItemsFieldInfoOptions = this.TypeItemsFieldData.values.filter(opt => opt.validFor.includes(0));
            }
        
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD})
    TypePicklistValues;

}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card >
    <template if:true={TypePicklistValues.data}>
        <template for:each={TypePicklistValues.data.values} for:item="item">
            <p key={item.value}>{item.value}</p>
            <template for:each={TypeItemsFieldInfoOptions} for:item="item">
            <lightning-input
                key={item.value}
                label={item.label}
                data-value={item.value}
                type="checkbox"
                ></lightning-input>
            </template>
        </template>
    </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the current index:

```
this.TypeItemsFieldInfoOptions = this.TypeItemsFieldData.values.filter(
  (opt,idx) => opt.validFor.includes(idx)
);
```

Comment: Thank you! But how will we get the current index?

Comment: @PriyaArun The second parameter to the Array.prototype.filter callback is the index of the current element you're checking for. Example is in the answer.

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new to javascript. But how are we passing the index of the current element ?